# How to use MultipleInheritance with postsharp

Tags: c#, compilation, aop, postsharp

How do you implement multiple inheritance with postsharp?
There is an example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/xafpoint/xafpointblogfiles/MultipleInheritance.rar?attredirects=0) but am new to postsharp. I cant port it to the latest
version of postsharp

Comment: Please ensure you read the tag information before using tags so that you don't inadvertently misuse any. The `visual-studio` tag is only intended for questions related to the Visual Studio application, and not code written with it.

Answer (score 1):

The [CompositionAspect](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_compositionaspect) is still available in the latest PostSharp. You will need to use the newer GetPublicInterfaces method, as well as handle generics differently (see [MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netcore-3.1)). We currently don't have samples for this.

However, you can also use [IntroduceInterfaceAttribute](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_introduceinterfaceattribute) on an aspect to inject behavior into a type. See [PostSharp documentation](https://doc.postsharp.net/code-injections#interfaces) for details. The aspect introducing the interface provides the implementation of the interface as well, so it would serve as a "base class". Using this, you can create the same pattern as in your example.

Note that true multiple implementation inheritance is not supported by C# or the CLR - these are patterns which allow you to simulate that.

Comment: This partly works for me.Is it possible to copy attributes on properties and methods to target class

Comment: It is possible, see [CopyCustomAttributesAttribute](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_copycustomattributesattribute).